# Using if/elif/else and resp=raw_input - how to respond to part of a user's input?

Tags: python

```
print "Please Type Something"
resp = raw_input()

if resp *contains* "cuttlefish"
    print  "Response One"
elif resp *contains* "nautilus"
    print "Response Two"
else:
    print "Response Three"
```

What I need to know is the correct syntax to use instead of the filler *contains*.  So, for example, if the user types  "two cuttlefish" then the program should respond by printing "Response One"

I did try look for this information in a few tutorials, so if you know of a good one that addresses this I wouldn't mind a pointer in that direction, either :/

Answer (score 5):

Python is quite an easy language, just think english and you might get it correct ;)

```
if 'cuttlefish' in resp:
```

Answer (score 3):

**in** is the operator you are looking for:

```
if "cuttlefish" in resp:
    print "Response One"
elif "nautilus" in resp:
    print "Response Two"
else:
    print "Response Three"
```

`in` is basically an operator that works on sequences like `str`, `tuple`, `list`. `x in y` checks if `x` is part of the sequence `y`. See also [5.6. Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange) in the Python Standard Library documentation.

#### edit

Regarding your second question *“Now, how do I change it so that "cuttlefish" is an entry on cuttlefishList, along with several other entries that should also trigger print "Response One"?”*.

That's actually a big more complicated, as you cannot check if any of multiple elements are within a sequence with in. But of course there are possibilities to do this. The simples ist to simply chain all the checks together:

```
if "cuttlefish" in resp or "someotherfish" in resp or "yetanotherfish" in resp:
    print "Response One"
```

If you have too many different words that would result in that response, then you can also *automate* that a bit like this:

```
if any( x in resp for x in ( "cuttlefish", "someotherfish", "yetanotherfish" ) ):
    print "Response One"
```

That is basically a short way of writing (not literally of course, but the idea is the same):

```
checkList = []
for x in ( "cuttlefish", "someotherfish", "yetanotherfish" ):
    checkList.append( x in resp )

if True in checkList:
    print "Response One"
```

So what it does is that it goes through all elements of your tuple and checks for each element `x` if it is part of the response. It keeps a check list of the results of these checks (in the short form, a generator does this). At the end, you check if `True` is part of the sequence `checkList`. If it does, at least one of the fishes were found in the response and you can print the result.

A different way would be to use regular expressions. It might be overkill to use them for a low number of different choices, but on the other hand, you could do great fancy stuff with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if "cuttlefish" in resp:
    # found
```

or

```
if resp.find("cuttlefish") > 0:
    # found
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax:

```
if 'string' in word:
   #Code
```

this checks if it is in word, regardless of it is a list or another string. So it would match True if word was 'foostringbar' or ['foo', 'string', 'bar']
Also, instead of printing to tell the user to enter something, try this:

```
resp = raw_input("Please Type Something\n")
```

This will produce the same thing, but is much more pythonic.